# Validation Rule add OR condition for record type and picklist

Tags: validation-rule

Trying to add an or condition to allow for more than one Record type to be allowed to have the picklist type value of *None.

Original:

```
AND(
$RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'A',
ISPICKVAL( Type , '*None'))
```

Proposed:

```
AND(
$RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'A' || $RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'B',
ISPICKVAL( Type , '*None'))
```

When I tested it I still get same error so I am thinking my syntax is incorrect.

--- Responding to Kris if this is an alternate way to write expression ---

```
AND(
NOT( OR(
$RecordType.DeveloperName = 'A',
$RecordType.DeveloperName = 'B',
ISPICKVAL( Type , '*None')
) ) )
```

Is one way better than another for any reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm assuming you want is the following:

User should be prevented from saving a record if *all* conditions are true:

1. Record Type is not `A`
2. Record Type is not `B`
3. `Type` is `*None`

Since you're just looking for all conditions to be `true`, they just need to be listed in a single `AND()` like so:

```
AND(
    $RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'A',
    $RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'B',
    ISPICKVAL(Type, '*None')
)
```

To explain why your attempt below didn't work

```
AND(
$RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'A' || $RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'B',
ISPICKVAL( Type , '*None'))
```

What you attempted above translates to the following:

User should be prevented from saving a record if *both* conditions are true:

1. The record type is not `A` **or** the record type is not `B`
2. `Type` is `*None`

You'll notice that condition 1 will always evaluate to true. Ex. if it's `B` then it's not `A`, if it's `A` then it's not `B`.

For your alternate suggestion below:

```
AND(
    NOT( 
        OR(
            $RecordType.DeveloperName = 'A',
            $RecordType.DeveloperName = 'B',
            ISPICKVAL( Type , '*None')
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

This translates to fire anytime *any* of the following conditions is true:

1. Record Type is not `A`
2. Record Type is not `B`
3. `Type` is not `*None`

So that wouldn't work as it'd block users even if they set the picklist to any other value. However, if you changed it to the following:

```
AND(
    NOT( 
        OR(
            $RecordType.DeveloperName = 'A',
            $RecordType.DeveloperName = 'B',
        )
    ),
    ISPICKVAL( Type , '*None')
)
```

It now changes to fire when the two conditions are true

1. If it's *not* `A` **or** `B`
2. Type is `*None`.

Which sounds like what you want. Whether that way is better than my initial suggestion on the top is probably debatable, but I always suggest the simpler version. In my top example, less parenthesis and less lines is usually a good initial rule of thumb. However, I would say the alternate version (with the correct logic) is viable as well and it's more about what your team is able to easily read.

---

Some tips/notes for readability for writing validation rules

1. Avoiding mixing `||` with `AND` if it's ever needed. `OR()` is easy to read and consistent with using `AND`
2. Indent like code so it's easier to catch the logic (as I've shown above). It doesn't seem necessary with small formulas, but is helpful for larger/complex formulas.

---

*Other Note:*

You might not even need a validation rule. You can remove picklist values from the dropdown in the UI per record type. Assuming there's no integration/apex setting this value, you can just remove `*None` from the `Selected Values` column for the identified record types (`A` and `B`) and users won't be able to select it.

`Setup --> Object Manager --> ObjectName --> Record Types --> Click Record Type --> Edit on picklist field`

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kris for such a detailed and thoughtful response.  Given what you said I am curious if I could also write the expression as follows.  I am adding to the original post since I can't seem to find a way to include it in comment.  I am going to be testing this as there is a flow that does set values before accepting the answer.

Comment: Seen your edit. I think readability is important. Large `NOT()` expressions can be hard to read immediately as it flips the expectation (and adds more parenthesis which can easily clutter) so I tend to suggest keeping it simple which usually means as close to as you would explain the logic in normal english. Obviously, there are some subjective elements to it. I would note, though, your alternate example doesn't seem to work. It would if you only wrapped your OR() part within the NOT().

Comment: Can you explain the wrapped your OR() ? Around each condition or the whole thing?  And I agree keep it simple.  It is just someone internally suggested it and I was just curious any benefit to doing it that way,

Comment: I added an edit for your alternate version and the correct version as well.

Comment: Thank you.  Very Helpful.  Soon as finish testing I will most likely accept the answer given as it looks right to me on the surface.